# Python unit test fails despite meeting requirement

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertion

I am doing an online python course that requires I complete some exercise to progress. The orginisers of this course says they have visible and hidden requirements a user must meet pass each test. In this case, the probelem statement is as follows:

> Write a function called manipulate_data which will act as follows:
>   When given a list of integers, return a list, where the first element is the count of positives numbers and the second element is the sum of negative numbers.
>   NB: Treat 0 as positive.

I came up with this, which I believe passes the visible requirement except maybe *line 6* of the unit test case

```
def manipulate_data(listinput):
    report = [0,0]
    if type(listinput) != list:
    #I may need some work here.. see unit test line 6
        assert "invalid argument" 
    for digit in listinput:
    #is an even number so we increment it by 1
        if digit >= 0 and type(digit) == int: 
            report[0] += 1
    #number is less than zero, adds it sum
        elif digit < 0 and type(digit) == int:
            report[1] += digit
    return report
```

EveryTime I run the code, I always get this Error message Indicating that my code passes 2 test out of three, which I assume is `test_only_list_allowed(self)` I am not really experienced with this kind of things and I need help. 
[image]

[image: Unit Test]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test shows that the code expected a string to be *returned*. `assert` raises an `AssertionError` exception instead. You want to return the same string as the `assertEquals()` test is looking for, so `'Only lists allowed'`, not the `msg` argument (which is shown when the test *fails*).

Instead of using `assert` use `return`, and return the expected string:

```
if type(listinput) != list:
    return "Only lists allowed"
```

Note that normally you'd use `isinstance()` to test for types:

```
if not isinstance(listinput, list):
    return "Only lists allowed" 
for digit in listinput:
    if not isinstance(digit, int):
        continue
    if digit >= 0: 
        report[0] += 1
    elif digit < 0:
        report[1] += digit
```

I used a single test for integers instead of testing in each branch. You could even have a type that doesn't support comparison with `0` so you want to get that test out of the way first.

Comment: Thanks, worked like charm. Been battling for days on this

Comment: I was wandering if you could take a look at related question that's giving issue on  [stackexchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338373/python-code-fails-unit-test-despite-meeting-requirement)

Comment: @Nexima360: please do *not* post code questions on the Software Engineering site. If you can't post it here because of a rate limit, then *wait until you can*, don't use another site where such questions are off-topic as a way to bypass the restrictions.